# creating an alias for python3

Tags: python, bash

I have python2.6.6 installed in my system. Now I am trying to use python3 while keeping all the python2.6.6 untouched in /usr/bin/. I am able to install python3 in /opt/python35/bin/. By adding `export PATH=/opt/python35/bin/:$PATH` to the ~/.bashrc file, I am able to access python3 anywhere in my console.

My question is: how could I set an alias (python) for python3 so that, whenever I issue command "python", python3 in /opt/python35/bin/ could be used? I simply couldn't remove python2.6.6 in my system due to some already installed programs in my system.

My current approach is to add a line in the ~/.bashrc file, `alias python = "/opt/python35/bin/python3"` or simply `alias python = "python3"`. However, when I reload this ~/.bashrc file, I got the following error:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
bash: alias: python: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: /opt/python35/bin/python3: not found
```

Does anybody know where my problem is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One caveat to doing this.  Some of the apps on your system that have a dependency on 2.6.6 may just be referencing `python`.  Aliasing `python` to `python35` may end up breaking these apps.  IMO you're better-off just specifying `python3` when you want to specifically use Python 3.5.  You can use this in your shebang line without any issues.

Answer (score 66):

Spaces are not allowed next to the equal sign when declaring aliases.

Use

```
alias python=python3
```

and it should work.

Comment: Put it in your `.bashrc`, otherwise it will only be parsed for login shells

Comment: You might also wanna do `alias pip=pip3`

Comment: This has no effect for me. which python shows /home/user/.local/pypoetry... alias python=[someotherpython] doesn't change it. Resourcing ". ~/.bashrc" doesn't have any effect either. Any suggestions?

Comment: @illan perhaps you are not using bash? macOS these days uses zsh by default.

Answer (score 16):

in your `.bashrc`

add

```
alias python='python3'
```

In bash script , you can't insert space beside `=` .

Comment: I couldn't make this work - it should, and I don't know why not. But creating the "missing" python file, containing the statement `python3`, did work.

Comment: This allows using another python, like python3.11, rather than python3

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

`apt install python-is-python3`

Comment: If you want to use another python that is not accesed by "python3" use alias method.

Answer (score 5):

An alias is nice an works great for a single User.

Sometime you need it for all Users Systemwide. Then create a symlink to point the /usr/bin/python command at the current default python3

`cd /usr/bin` and `sudo ln -s python3 /usr/bin/python`

You can check the result with `ls -la python*` and `python --version`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `echo alias python=python3 >> .zshrc` and `echo alias pip=pip3 >> .zshrc`. If you use bash instead of zsh then just replace `.zshrc` with `.bashrc`. If using an older version of ubuntu, you might have to install  and pip3.

Comment: try this if your current directory is not home directory. ```echo alias python=python3 >> ~/.zshrc``` and ```echo alias pip=pip3 >> ~/.zshrc```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a python virtual environment in the your project folder:

```
python3.10 -m venv .venv
```

Instead of 3.10 place your python version.
Then activate it:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Then create a symlink for python as You wish:

```
ln -s .venv/bin/python .venv/bin/pluton
```

Then You can run python under desired name:

```
pluton my_program.py
```

Comment: It seems the question was more about the shell configuration than the python environment.

Answer (score -1):

Or, if you like, append these inside `bash_profile`:

```
python(){
python3
}
```

Comment: This does not pass any command-line arguments through to `python3`