# How to setup default Python version and pip? [macOS]

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I'm having serious troubles on configuring my Python. I want use the Spyder IDE but I can't configure the default Python on system.

In resume I configured Python path to point to: `/usr/bin/python3` on .bash_profile, but the default python env points to other local that I don't know neither the reason neither true local. I've checked it with `python -V` and `which python`, it return to me `python 2.7.16`.

[image]

```
MacBook-Air-de-Augusto-2:~ augustosansoncadini$ /usr/bin/python3 -V
Python 3.8.2
```

My goal is just configure default Python path to `/usr/bin/python3` and `pip` to this too.

Comment: not the answer to your question per se, but have you tried using `python3` in the console? Do you actually need to have the keyword "python" point there or would that be sufficient

Comment: `alias python='/whatever/path/to/python_interpreter'` ?

Comment: You need to create an alias in your bashrc, or corresponding file for zsh depending on your shell. In your bashrc, you are just creating a variable called `python` instead. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435517/creating-an-alias-for-python3

Comment: If you are using macOS then the default shell is zsh. If you have to change .zshrc not .bash_profile.

Comment: There are none .zshrc file.