# python3 command works on mac OS, but python is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

The command `python` is not found.

This is where python3 is installed.

```
~ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

How do I get the command `python` to mean `python3`?

Comment: It depends on the shell you're using. For bash/zsh, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967843/how-do-i-create-a-bash-alias

Answer (score 1):

You can add an alias in your shell.

NOTE: be careful with this, though, because if you're using a virtual environment, it doesn't always play nice with aliases you've defined outside the environment.

For example, if you use bash, you can add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
alias python=python3
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35435574/11411191

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an alias in your shell or symlink the `python3` binary to `python`. Symlinking is easier and will work no matter which shell or virtual environment you are using. Just run this command:

```
ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: After the symlinking i get this error: `xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python', requesting installation of command line developer tools.`

Comment: You need to install the command line developer tools. They're just basic tools you'll need for development, regardless of language.

Comment: Why would you need to install developer tools? If `python3` works fine, and `/usr/local/bin/python` is symlinked to the same binary, why shouldn't that just work?

Comment: @BenDavis Even if `python3` is found, installing the developer tools can't hurt. At least on my machine, the developer tools link `python` to Python 2.7.16. This answer should be an extension of what the developer tools give you.